# Background music overlap when back to creator viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, avfoundation

I have a game which consists of 3 view controllers:

- viewController
- settingViewController
- GameViewController

I have set the background music and played it in the viewController class

```
var backgroundMusic : AVAudioPlayer!
func setUpSounds(){
        //button sound
        if let buttonSoundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("buttonClick", ofType: "mp3") {
            let buttonSoundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: buttonSoundPath)
            do {
                try buttonSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: buttonSoundURL)
            }catch {
                print("could not setup button sound")
            }
            buttonSound.volume = 0.5
        }
        //background sound
        if let backgroundMusicPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("BackgroundMusic", ofType: "mp3") {
            let backgroundMusicURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: backgroundMusicPath)
            do {
                try backgroundMusic = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: backgroundMusicURL)
            }catch {
                print("could not setup background music")
            }
            backgroundMusic.volume = 0.2
            /*
            set any negative integer value to loop the sound
            indefinitely until you call the stop method
            */
            backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1
        }
    }


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setUpSounds()
        self.playBackgroundSound()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

when I move to the settingViewController then back again to the viewController the sound replay and overlap the old played music.

What is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if the `AVAudioPlayer` is playing a music before call `playBackgroundSound`.

You can also put your SoundManager as a singleton, so you can manipulate it, from other parts of the app.

```
    class SoundManager{
        static var backgroundMusicSharedInstance = AVAudioPlayer?
    }
```

---

In the View

```
    func setUpSounds(){
            //background sound

       if SoundManager.backgroundMusicSharedInstance == nil {
            if let backgroundMusicPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("BackgroundMusic", ofType: "mp3") {
                let backgroundMusicURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: backgroundMusicPath)
                do {
                    try SoundManager.backgroundMusicSharedInstance = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: backgroundMusicURL)
                }catch {
                    print("could not setup background music")
                }
                SoundManager.backgroundMusicSharedInstance!.volume = 0.2
                /*
                set any negative integer value to loop the sound
                indefinitely until you call the stop method
                */
                SoundManager.backgroundMusicSharedInstance!.numberOfLoops = -1
            }
        }
}


    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.setUpSounds()
             if SoundManager.backgroundMusicSharedInstance!.playing == false{
                  self.playBackgroundSound()
              }    
    }
```

Comment: didn't help, Still the same problem.

Comment: Are you using modal or push segue?

Comment: i've connected it using the storyboard

Comment: Ok, but how are you setting the segues? when you click in the connection, what name is show in the right? look at this link http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzo4p.png

Comment: show (e.g push) this is what's showing in my case also

Comment: @AliAlebrahim Do this test, put a breakpoint in the setUpSounds(), when you return, check the content of the backgroundMusic object, I think that you are creating a new object, and the older one is continuing playing.

Comment: @AliAlebrahim, Do you have an navigation controller? are you using dismiss to get back to the other view?

Comment: no, im using another button to get me back to the viewController.

Comment: @AliAlebrahim, You are loosing the reference to that object, thats why you cannot see if it's still playing.
Use a navigation view controller, to get back to that old view (or use a modal presentation of your settings view, and get back with a dismiss), or move your sound to a singleton manager.

Comment: can you please write a detailed answer on how to move the sound to a singleton manager ? if that is ok with you

Comment: Edited the answer, I wrote without testing it, please verify it there is no compile problem.

Comment: Thank you very much !! it works perfectly. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: :) Happy to be helpful.

Comment: i just had to change it to this ..  static var backgroundMusicSharedInstance = AVAudioPlayer?() to work.

Comment: ups, I edited the post to the correct statement, ty.